# flutterfire configure doesn't work in the terminal

Tags: firebase

While attempting to initialize firebase in my project I constantly had an information in my terminal: 'flutterfire configure - command not found'. I followed every step from the documentation and added a new path as my terminal suggested. The only thing that worked for me was typing in my project terminal  :

```
dart pub global run flutterfire_cli:flutterfire configure
```

instead of flutterfire configure. For anybody having the same issue I suggest to try out this one, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Flutterfire is not in your PATH. Activate it globally, then flutterfire configure will work. You can do this by replacing the run with activate: dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli.